# Finding a function for a given input and set of outputs

Tags: function, math, input, output

I want to write a computer program that will give a list of "simple" functions when given a single input and a range of possible outputs. I know infinitely many functions will be given and it is impossible to give a function for every single output (since there are infinitely many real numbers between any two real numbers). For the range of outputs, I want to restrict the outputs to having 2 or so significant digits, and I want a list of "simple functions" ( simple is based on the functions degree and its coefficients)

For example, suppose I want to find a function for a set of values (1,a), (2,b), (3,c) where a is between 7 and 8 inclusive, b is between 9 and 10 inclusive, and c is between 11 and 12 inclusive. How would I generate a list of such simple functions?

I did some research on this topic but could not find an answer to this question. I find a program that gives a list of functions based on a set of input and output values (for some reason the program didn't work) but nothing for a range of output values.

Also, the length of the range of each output is 1.

Thanks so much, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A simple - though far from optimal - way would be a least squares fit with increasing degree (until the function fits in all ranges).

Answer (score 1):

I consider only polynomial solutions. You can use a loop which increases the degree of the function, then in each iteration uses a linear program to check whether there exists a feasible solution for that degree. Checking for feasibility you don't need a target function. Keep in mind that a polynomial function is polynomial in its input, but linear in its coefficients, which is the reason why a linear program will work here.

If you want to not only minimize the degree, but also keep coefficients simple, things may become more complicated. In particular, if you want a fixed number of digits per coefficient, you enter the domain of integer programming problems, which is even harder.